# is there a way to return last file in the subfolders when using PowerShell

Tags: sql, powershell, azure-sql-database

I have PowerShell script and i want to return multiple folders based on their positional using a wile card ex. sqlfile*\table i get-childitems -recurse. Thank you

Comment: You can recurse through the file tree and once the folder does not contain any  more folders, you stop. Either you use `.GetFileSystemInfos.Count() -eq 0` or with `Measure-Object` you find the last folder.

Comment: i though using Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $sqlFilesfolder -Filter *.sql was enough to recurse through the @sqlFilesFolder which in my case is udw_db and then will return the file which ends .sql which is view_Nuradin_UnitTest.sql

Comment: Yes, this filter will show all files in this path which ends in .sql. I thought however you want to find the last folder and not just a particular file extension.

Comment: I want to return the newest and last file which is in the end of the last subfolder. I am not sure the term recurse needs to go after the -Path. I just not getting the last file when i run this in my pipeline. its just not returning anything.  here is what am getting in my result - it looks for a file but then says found this -- an empy pretty much.                                  Looking for sql files in D:\a\r1\a/_AzureUDW/drop/udw_db
2020-05-30T20:56:52.5385009Z Found the following files:
2020-05-30T20:56:52.5986114Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy SQL Scripts

Comment: FYI, -recurse, is not positional. You can put it anywhere in the command.

Answer (score 1):

> "I want to return the newest and last file which is in the end of the
>   last subfolder."

Is this what you are going for based on your comment above?

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path D:\Temp -Directory

# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                               
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                               
d-----        06-May-20     20:30                AddressFiles                                                                                                       
d-----        17-Feb-20     15:50                est                                                                                                                
d-----        14-Mar-20     17:03                here                                                                                                               
d-----        26-May-20     10:38                hold                                                                                                               
d-----        06-May-20     20:30                LogFiles                                                                                                           
d-----        06-Feb-20     14:56                NewFolder                                                                                                          
d-----        12-Feb-20     14:24                ParentFolder                                                                                                       
d-----        03-Feb-20     11:55                Reference                                                                                                          
d-----        06-Feb-20     14:56                Source                                                                                                             
d-----        24-Feb-20     22:03                Target                                                                                                             
d-----        22-May-20     20:51                Zips                                                                                                               


    Directory: D:\Temp\NewFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                               
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                               
d-----        03-Feb-20     11:55                New folder                                                                                                         
d-----        20-Jan-20     11:17                temp                                                                                                               


    Directory: D:\Temp\ParentFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                               
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                               
d-----        12-Feb-20     14:08                ChildFolder                                                                                                        


    Directory: D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                               
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                               
d-----        12-Feb-20     14:08                GrandchildFolder  
#>

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path D:\Temp -Directory | 
Select-Object -Last 1

# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                               
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                               
d-----        12-Feb-20     14:08                GrandchildFolder 
#>

(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path D:\Temp -Directory | 
Select-Object -Last 1).Fullname

# Results

<#
D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\GrandchildFolder
#>

$LastSubFolder = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path D:\Temp -Directory | 
Select-Object -Last 1).Fullname  

Get-ChildItem -Path $LastSubFolder 

# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\GrandchildFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                               
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                               
-a----        28-Aug-07     13:08        2646058 GrandchildThumperLong.wav                                                                                          
-a----        28-Aug-07     13:05         683670 GrandchildThumperShort.wav                                                                                         
-a----        23-Apr-99     18:22         668440 GrandchildWELCOM98.WAV 
#>

Get-ChildItem -Path $LastSubFolder | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime

# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\GrandchildFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                               
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                               
-a----        23-Apr-99     18:22         668440 GrandchildWELCOM98.WAV                                                                                             
-a----        28-Aug-07     13:05         683670 GrandchildThumperShort.wav                                                                                         
-a----        28-Aug-07     13:08        2646058 GrandchildThumperLong.wav  
#>

Get-ChildItem -Path $LastSubFolder | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | 
Select-Object -First 1 -Last 1

# Results
<#

    Directory: D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\GrandchildFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                               
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                               
-a----        23-Apr-99     18:22         668440 GrandchildWELCOM98.WAV                                                                                             
-a----        28-Aug-07     13:08        2646058 GrandchildThumperLong.wav  

#>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail response - my only concern about this logic is, isn't there a way to pass a simple iterative by only passing on my powershell script folder at the highest level folder(parent) which in this case is udw_db and in your example assume to be the D:\temp but then can have multiple folders each consisting folders such as view folder, stored proc folder, table, etc. so a developer can post a .sql file for a view and i want my pipeline recursively go through and pick the last file that ends with *.sql and run that executing sql command. so yes - i want return the last file.

Comment: so to answer your question - my parent folder is udw_db at all times but there subfolders and at given time new file can be added to one of the sub-child folders - so these can change but the parent stays consistent. thats why i used $sqlFilesfolder which in my case is variable that is set to udw_db parent folder. all i want is how do i pass the parent folder variable $sqlFilesfolder and iterate through folders to get to the last file that ends with *.sql using the -Filter keyword. you are right on your logic above but are you also saying i have to specify each folder to the root level ?